# Swift - App calling service has connection error due to TLSv1.3

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, https

The https service was working till few days back from devices in debug.

I am getting the error while debugging my code. The https connection is unable to connect to site.

This error is related to "TLSv1.3"

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
HTTP load failed (error code: -1200 [3:-9824])
finished with error - code: -1200
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." 
UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9824, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, 
NSUnderlyingError=0x1c405c860 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" 
UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9824, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9824}}, 
NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://..., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://..., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
```

I do NOT need the old solution of adding key NSAppTransportSecurity in info plist file.

When checking with website following command in terminal on mac

```
nscurl --ats-diagnostics https://....com --verbose
```

I get following exception.

```
TLSv1.3
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        ".....com" =         {
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.3";
        };
    };
}
```

The same website is TLSv1.2 compliant.

As per other documents in following links, it is found that "TLSv1.3" is still not made mandatory by Apple.

1) [SSL Connection Error with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50341620/2641380)

2) https://www.internetsociety.org/blog/2017/06/mptcp-and-tls-1-3-big-announcements-from-apple/

Has anybody started facing this error recently while connecting from iOS app to any https connection, when their website is TLSv1.2 compliant but not for TLSv1.3 ?

If anyone has found the solution or temporary solution, please post it here.

Thanks and Regards

Sanjay.

**Update** 25th Jul 2018.

Today it started working. I am not sure of error on server side or any other network error. The website is still non-compliant to TLSv1.3, but service is working like earlier.

Thanks @Maik639 for your suggestion.

Comment: Is it possible that your certificate is not valid? You could try to disable certificate validation inside your app. If that works it has to do something with that. You can add the NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads key to your plist to test that. I know, you said that you do not need the ATS-Fix but this one might help. (As a temporary fix)

Comment: hmmm any updates on this? Also anyone knows how does one check if the cert is valid?!